# Tampermonkey Scripts not running in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I just found out about Tampermonkey a few hours ago and have tried to play around with it. It seems cool and I have the extension running a few premade scripts. However when I try to run a very simple script of my own:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Alert Page Title
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://community.wanikani.com
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(title);
    console.log(title);
})();
```

just to test it out the script doesn't run. It works fine when I try it on Chrome but doesn't seem to run on Safari. Tampermonkey recognizes that the extension's compatible page has been loaded with the ⓵ appearing on its icon so the URL regex is fine.

This seems like a really stupid question I know but after a few hours of Googling I can't seem to find anything about this. I'm running MacOS 10.15.1 with Safari 13.0.3; the version of Tampermonkey I'm using is the one installed from the MacOS App Store.

Edit: It was noted that the `@run-at` line might cause errors so I removed it. Also I have include the console logs for both Chrome and Safari.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzjmn.png)

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUocE.png)

Comment: Any console errors? You're running on `document-start`, but you're trying to find a `title` element. If the injection is instant, no element will be found, because the DOM isn't populated yet

Comment: That's a good point! Though, sadly that wasn't the issue. When I load the page both with/out that line the reposes are the the same (there are errors but they come from the webpage itself not the script.

Comment: The first error in Safari's console says Tampermonkey couldn't run the userscript due to the page CSP.

Comment: When you switch Tampermonkey options to "Advanced" mode there should be a setting about `CSP` (use find-in-page to locate it). At least it's present in Chrome/FF versions. Otherwise you would need an additional extension that relaxes the CSP of the page. Also try asking on Tampermonkey forum/github.

Comment: That setting doesn't exist in the Safari version of Tampermonkey. It seems like it's a common issue with not just Safari but other browsers as well, but I don't think you can disable CSP outright in Safari. It just seems strange that the two other scripts that I have tried using don't have any issues, and they are for the same site that I'm trying to use as well.

Comment: Those other scripts may have a different `@grant`. Try specifying `@grant GM_info` instead of `none`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ```@grant``` does, but it didn't seem to do much.

Comment: Well, compare the headers of the scripts and see what's different. Something must be.